# Incompatibility Issues between Access Database Engine and Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access, registry, rodbc, incompatibility

I installed **Access Database Engine** in order to open a database using **RStudio** and everything is fine. However when I installed the package, Microsoft Access **can't start** which means that if I try opening any Access file or creating any new one, it won't open. 
Therefore, there is **incompatibility issue** between Access file and Access Database Engine, since I tried this process on **two different platforms** and got the same problem. Therefore, I appreciate any ideas or solutions regarding fixing the issue using **registry** or other suggestions.

Comment: Microsoft Access consists of much more than the database engine. And it's not for free.

Answer (score 1):

As Andre altready mentioned - there is a misunderstanding on your side. Access runtime can ONLY open existing databases for data entry, nothing else. No alteration of forms, no new reports, and especially no new table or database. For stuff like this you need the whole access application, which is part of office and far from free.

Comment: Well, I didn't see the answer to my question, since he talks about some details related to MS-Access. Therefore, he says in indirect way that you can't solve the problem for free. However, the solution was to re-install office and it worked !!

Comment: What you said is to clarify how it works. Of course it is used for data entry. However, we all know that if some issues happen in registry you need to fix it or re-install all again. My question was to know if there is a way to fix the registry or to find any other tool or suggestion not how MS-Access works or what it contains. Anyway thank you both for your contribution